# Android Studio Virtual Devices are gone (Emulator)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I just started to work and noticed that something is wrong with AndroidStudio. I have 3 Emulators that I've been using for some time. TODAY tho when I went inside AS I only have the option to create new Emulators but I cant use my old ones.

I still can see them inside the .android folder under avd - but not inside AS eventhough the Path for the SDK is the right one and hasnt changed since yesterday where everything worked as expected.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches/restart for your AS?

Comment: What do you mean by that can you explain?

Comment: On your AS got to File then you will find "invalidate caches/restart" in this menu.

Comment: I did that and it didnt change anything - the problem is also that AS has a problem with my SDK validation because I set the AndoridSDKhome path to something else on my C disk. Its weird because yesterday everything worked and nothing changed since

Comment: Why you changed your SDK path !?

Comment: Because it takes to much space inside my userprofile.. just makes no sense because its been like this for months without any issues :/

Comment: ___ OK i fixxed it for some reason I had to change the ANDROID SDK HOME var again because it was wrong - which still doesnt make sense to me because it was working fine the other day but it works now